# Include documentation in a JAR file

Tags: eclipse, jar, documentation, javadoc

With Eclipse it is possible to attach a documentation folder to a jar file in order to see the jar classes' documentation while programming. My question is: is it possible to directly include the documentation into the jar file, in order to avoid the programmer to link the two parts every time they need to use the jar file? (and so to let me to distribute just a jar file, rather than a zip file with the jar and its documentation).

#### EDIT

final result: **it is impossible.** :(

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what do you mean with "directly include the documentation", but you can put anything in the jar file. If you use ant (it can be inside Eclipse), just create a target for your distribution build and pass the documentation folder to [Jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).

```
  <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/app.jar">
    <fileset dir="${build}/classes"
             excludes="**/Test.class"
    />
    <fileset dir="${src}/documentation"/>
  </jar>
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can put what I want in the jar file. What I want to know is if I can avoid to link manually the jar file with its documentation.

Comment: Yes, you can - customizing your build script. The snippet in my answer was adapted from the examples on the link. It will create a jar file with the contents of `${build}/classes` folder, excluding any file called `Test.class`, and the contents of `${src}/documentation`. I don't know if you use Ant with Eclipse. I don't use Eclipse, but know you can customize your build script (even if you don't use Ant, there will be a way to do this with Maven or any other build system).

Comment: I succedeed with putting doc files into the jar file. The problem is that the documentation is still not visible if the jar file is not explicitly linked with the jar file...

Comment: I don't get what you mean with "if the jar file is not explicitly linked with the jar file". Is it creating a jar for your project, with the javadocs inside, and reading the javadocs from the file you didn't create yet?

Comment: I mean: if I want to use a jar file programming with Eclipse I want the programmer can see its documentation. With Eclipse you can link the jar file with its documentation, in order to see it while writing the code. I just want to avoid the user to explicitly link the jar file with its documentation files, but I would like to a do this job automatically...

Comment: Now I got it. I think there is no other way to do this in a purely automatic way. In `Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries` you can create user libraries that can hold various jar files. There you can define where is the javadoc. And "importing" this to your project, the javadoc will be already linked.